# Add type parameter k to meth() mean?

Tags: java

I am new to Java and I couldn't understand the difference between

```
public static <V> void meth()
```

and

```
public static void meth()
```

Q1. What does <V> mean as a parameter? It's a generic type and does that mean the method returns/takes a parameter of type V??

Here's my code:

```
public static <V> void meth(){
     Map<K, V> m = new HashMap<K, V>();
}
```

Then the compiler shows error:

" Add type parameter 'k' to meth()< V > "
Q2.What does this mean??

Answer (score 1):

You are using a generic type (`Map<K, V>` and `HashMap<K, V>`) but `K` isn't declared or known as a type. So you either need to create a class `K` or add a type parameter `K` to the method so the compiler knows what `K` should be when it's used.

Comment: Does that mean, if we write something like < V > in between static and void then it should be a generic type,right?

Comment: No, then it's a generic method. And you need to use `<K, V>` there to stop the compiler from complaining.

Comment: I am not sure whether I framed the question correctly or not. I would like to explain it again. How come "public static <V> void meth() " become a generic method??(< v > IN BETWEEN STATIC AND VOID). I guess public static <V> void meth(< V >) becomes a generic method.

Comment: Yes, if you add a generic type parameter to a method, then it becomes a generic method.

Answer (score 1):

You're using generics.

K and V aren't defined types in your example. They are used to create generic class that acts the same way with different datatype.

There you go if you want to read more about it.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java

In short, you may have something like that.

- `List` # will contain any object that is an Object
- `List<Integer>` will be a list of integers.
- `List<String>` will be a list of string

So instead of `K, V`, you could have something like `Map<Integer, String>` ...

In generics, the parameter you put there is a classname instead of a variable.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I am bit confused about Generics but I guess it's clarified now. I don't know that the parameter should be a class name.

Comment: It's not all!! For example, `Map<String, Integer>(variables...)`, what is between `<` and `>` are classes name, and between `(` and `)` variables as usual if needed.